# Set the checkboxes for a Filament Checkboxlist based on another field value and a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I have a Laravel Filament `Checkboxlist` named `contact_ids`:

```php
CheckboxList::make('contact_ids')
    ->reactive()
    ->options([])
    ->searchable()
    ->columns(1),
```

I want to display the checkboxes that appear on this list based on a relationship:

```php
public function contacts(): HasManyThrough {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Contact::class, Client::class);
}
```

I've tried to add some reactivity to my `Select::make('client_id')` like this:

```php
Select::make('client_id')
    ->relationship('client', 'name')
    ->searchable(['name'])
    ->preload()
    ->required()
    ->reactive()
    ->createOptionForm(Client::getForm())
    ->afterStateUpdated(function ($set, $state) {
                              // Update the options for the contact_ids CheckboxList based on the selected client
                              $set('contact_ids', []); // Clear the selected contacts when the client changes
                              $contacts = Contact::where('client_id', $state)->pluck('last_name', 'id');
                              $set('contact_ids.options', $contacts); // Update the options for the CheckboxList
                          }),
```

But this does not update the checkboxlist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the CheckboxList options method to reference this reactive state, ensuring it updates when the state changes

```
Select::make('client_id')
    ->relationship('client', 'name')
    ->searchable(['name'])
    ->preload()
    ->required()
    ->reactive()
    ->createOptionForm(Client::getForm())
    ->afterStateUpdated(function ($set, $state) {
        $contacts = Contact::where('client_id', $state)->pluck('last_name', 'id')->toArray();
        $set('contactsOptions', $contacts);
    }),

CheckboxList::make('contact_ids')
    ->reactive()
    ->options(fn($get) => $get('contactsOptions') ?: [])
    ->searchable()
    ->columns(1),
```

Comment: Isn't dehydrateStateUsing used to modify the state when the form is send?

Comment: oh sorry, that was a misunderstanding, let me go through it again.

Comment: Awesome. This was really giving me a hard time. Works like a charm.